# With What Hardware and Software Configuration Could One Continuously Sync Localhost with Remotehost (with low power cost)?

Tags: linux, embedded

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this --- if it isn't, I'll delete it.

The question is prompted by the internet speeds at my address. To download a large file (say, 4GiB or so) several hours or more are needed.

Thus the answer to this question would (maybe/likely) include/be a linux on a board that has a very low power draw and that has a usb port so that storage can be added to it, in addition to Ethernet connection. This would be connected to the (slow) internet connection and left on 24/7. At certain times of the day a script will run which will trigger the system to sync its files with Remotehost. So that's,

ETHERNET --> SOME_TYPE_OF_LINUX_SMALL_SYSTEM -- SCRIPTS -- --> EXTERNAL HARD DRIVE

Software wise I suppose any distribution would do; seemingly a headless system would be best so perhaps Arch linux. The biggest part of the question is then, if you agree with what I presume to be the best way to go about this, what hardware models/company makes such a device?

EDIT: The answer should not be the raspi, but rather an already assembled unit.

Answer (score 2):

There are several small Linux systems, but the only one I am familiar with is the Raspberry PI.

I would use the Raspbian distribution (based on debian).

[Download daemon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/downloaddaemon/) seems like it would be suitable for your downloads as it has a remote client interface.

Cron could be used to run rsync (to do the file sync) at certain times, but why not just share the external disk?

Comment: Thanks! I know that's great, but I'd rather have something already assembled.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Pogoplug](https://pogoplug.com/). If you does not happy with there built-in cloud service, you could also try to install [ArchLinux](http://archlinuxarm.org/) on it.